# Intellij on Linux: Menu: jdk > javap option

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, ide, javap

I use Intellij community 2018 on Ubuntu. How can I have a `jdk` option in the menu that appears after right clicking inside the editor window?

I don't know if this option is built into the IDE or some external plugin.

This `jdk` option should have (at least) 2 `javap` options to disassemble class files.
See the following screen shot. Taken from an older Intellij on Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) to run `javap` on the active file using the `$FilePath$` macro as an argument. Set the tool group to `jdk`.

If you want to get the output for the `.class` file while right clicking inside the source `.java` file, you may use something like this for the argument: `$OutputPath$/$FileDirRelativeToSourcepath$/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.class`

Note that IntelliJ IDEA has a built-in disassembler and some third-party plug-ins to view the byte code, so you may not need this tool at all.

Comment: Thanks! Built in disassembler? How to access it? Is it different in its capabilities from the bytecode plugins? I installed the `ASM Bytecode Viewer` plugin version 6.0.1 with a bytecode tab and ASM code tab... but it does not show a constant table like I see when I run `javap -verbose` from the terminal. You can see what I mean in this tutorial: https://vimeo.com/52990474 time: 11:40

Comment: You can click on a `.class` file in IntelliJ IDEA and it will open the disassembled source code. There is also a built-in `View` | `Show Byte Code` action, but it doesn't show the Constant pool like `javap`.

Comment: @rapt did my answer help to get the javap external tool working?

Comment: I apologize, I did not have time to test it. I will definitely check and let you know. In the meanwhile, thanks for replying.